# binding app component property from other child component

Tags: angular

i want to show and hide my navs in app component by a shared service.
when  call this._service.setLogin() in component the _service.Login, property will be set to true but not affected to app component and binding not work

this is my app component

```
@Component({
selector: 'pm-app',  
templateUrl: "/app/app.component.html",providers:AuthenticationService]      
 ,providers: [AuthenticationService]
  })
 constructor(private _service: AuthenticationService) {}

<nav class="off-canvas-navigation">

            <li *ngIf='!_service.Login'><a [routerLink]="['/login']">login</a></li>
            <li *ngIf='_service.Login'><a [routerLink]="['/logout']">logOut</a></li>
        </nav>
        <div id="page-content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
</nav>
```

and my shared shared sevice is bellow

```
  @Injectable()
    export class AuthenticationService {
    Login: boolean;

    setLogin(){this.login=true;}
```

and my another component is here

```
   @Component({ 
   templateUrl: "app/home/login-form.component.html",
  providers: [AuthenticationService]
   })
  export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private _service: AuthenticationService) {}
   login() {this._service.setLogin();}
}
```

Comment: `providers` in component decorator? Which angular 2 version is this?

Comment: i set the providers. angular 2 rc5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `providers` meta property in component creates *different instance* of your service,

so to make it work, you should put **`providers`** in your **`rootmodule`** as shown below,

*(also don't forget to remove providers from @Component decorator)*

**AppModule.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   providers: [AuthenticationService]   //<<## add here in NgModule decorator
})
```